# Question about proof of no retraction theorem in 2 dimensions

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-explanation, geometric-topology, spheres

I am reading Colin Buxton's proof of the no retraction theorem in 2 dimensions on pages 9 and 10 here: http://math.stmarys-ca.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Colin-Buxton.pdf.

There is one step I am not convinced of. First I introduce the notation relevant to my question.

$\textbf{NOTATION:}$

$\mathbb{D} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x||\leq 1\}$,

$C=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x||=1\}$,

$r:\mathbb{D} \rightarrow C$ is a retraction (which we assume exists for contradiction),

$a, b \in C$ with $a \neq b$,

and $A=r^{-1}(\{a\}), B=r^{-1}(\{b\})$.

$\textbf{MY CONFUSION:}$

Buxton says: "Note that $\overline{C\diagdown \{a, b\}}=C$. We can, then, find a subset of $\mathbb{D}\diagdown (A \cup B)$ whose closure will contain $C$. Let us call this set $P$. We can choose $P$ to be open and $\textit{path connected}$."

$\textbf{How can we choose $P$ to be path connected?}$

It is clear to me that we can choose $P$ to be open and contain $C$ in its closure. For example, let $B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||x||<1\}$. Then clearly $P=B \diagdown (A \cup B)$ will be open and $C \subseteq \overline{P}$. However, no reason jumps out at me why $P$ can be chosen to be path connected.

I am probably missing something terribly simple.

Thank you!

Comment: They copied the argument (incomplete) from their third reference, who copied it (incomplete) from [this one](https://www.cmi.ac.in/~sourav/papers/topology.pdf). The whole substance of the proof goes into the assertion that $P$ is connected.